# Как работает следующий код?

Tags: c++

**Пример 1:**

```
class A;class B;class C;

void A::showcase()
{
    C *ptr = new C(*this);
    B.input(ptr);
}
```

**Пример 2:**

```
class A;class C;class B;

void A::showcase()
{
    B.input(new C(*this)); 
}
```

Удаляется ли указатель в первом примере?

Comment: Удаляется не указатель, а объект, на который указывает указатель, и только при вызове `delete`.

Comment: Про delete я ничего не говорил а удаляется как раз таки локальный указатель после выхода из функции класса. Сам объект удаляется в классе B.

Comment: Так все дело в том, что что-то может удаляться только при вызове `delete`. Если `input` не вызывает `delete`, то ни в первом, ни во втором случае ничего не удаляется.

Comment: @user7860670, все дело в том , что что-то может удаляться только при вызове delete? А как же локальная переменная? Их удаление не требуют оператора delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Локальная переменная-указатель - удаляется при выходе из методa. Объект на который она указывает - не удаляется.

Comment: Вы про первый пример? А во втором?

Comment: @0x00004 Что во втором? Там нет явно объявленных локальных переменных.

Comment: То есть локальный указатель ptr в первом примере удаляется и между этими двумя примерами нет никакой разницы?

Comment: @0x00004 Как - нет разницы? А звeздочка перед `this`?

Comment: моя ошибка.Исправил. Итог: Оба примера не имеют никакой разницы.

Answer (score -1):

Локальные переменные имеют автоматическое хранение и не удаляются в принципе. Удалятся могут только переменные с динамическим хранением (то бишь созданные вызовом `new`) и только при вызове соответствующего `delete`. Так что если `input` не использует `delete`, то ни в первом, ни во втором случае ничего не удаляется.